# Hibernate validator always says that collection is empty

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, annotations

I'm having a really hard time to figure this out. I have two classes Employee and Role:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employees")
public class Employee implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5468763051360122059L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "employee_guid", length = 36)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 36, max = 36)
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "is_active", nullable = false)
    private boolean isActive;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "employees", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {
        CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH,
        CascadeType.DETACH })
    @NotEmpty
    @Valid
    private List<Role> roles;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "employee", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {
        CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH,
        CascadeType.DETACH }, orphanRemoval = true)
    @Valid
    private List<VacationRequest> vacationRequests;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "manager", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {
        CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH,
        CascadeType.DETACH }, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<ManagerSubordinate> managers;

    protected Employee() {
        vacationRequests = new ArrayList<VacationRequest>();
        managers = new ArrayList<ManagerSubordinate>();
    }

    public Employee(UUID id, List<Role> roles) {
        this(id, roles, true);
    }

    public Employee(UUID id, List<Role> roles, boolean isActive) {
        this();

        if (id == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("id cannot be null");
        }

        this.id = id.toString();
        this.roles = roles;
        this.isActive = isActive;
    }

    public UUID getId() {
        return UUID.fromString(id);
    }

    public boolean isActive() {
        return isActive;
    }

    public void setActive(boolean isActive) {
        this.isActive = isActive;
    }

    public List<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(List<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    public List<VacationRequest> getVacationRequests() {
        return vacationRequests;
    }

    public void setVacationRequests(List<VacationRequest> vacationRequests) {
        this.vacationRequests = vacationRequests;
    }

    public List<ManagerSubordinate> getManagers() {
        return managers;
    }

    public void setManagers(List<ManagerSubordinate> managers) {
        this.managers = managers;
    }
}



 @Entity
    @Table(name = "application_roles", uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(name =             "UK_ROLE_NAME",
        columnNames = "name") })
public class Role implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6126630712163059772L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 50)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 5, max = 50)
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST,
        CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.DETACH })
    @JoinTable(name = "employees_application_roles", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "employee_guid",
        nullable = false) }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", nullable = false) },
            foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_EMPLOYEE_ROLE", value = ConstraintMode.CONSTRAINT),
            inverseForeignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_ROLE_EMPLOYEE", value = ConstraintMode.CONSTRAINT))
    @Valid
    private List<Employee> employees;

    protected Role() {
        employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();
    }

    public Role(String name) {
        this();

        this.name = name;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<Employee> getEmployees() {
        return employees;
    }

    public void setEmployees(List<Employee> employees) {
        this.employees = employees;
    }
}
```

Additionally Employee has many to many relationship with itself:

```
@Embeddable
public class ManagerSubordinateId implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2145140927848605356L;

    @Column(name = "manager_guid", length = 36)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 36, max = 36)
    private String managerId;

    @Column(name = "subordinate_guid", length = 36)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 36, max = 36)
    private String subordinateId;

    protected ManagerSubordinateId() {
    }

    public ManagerSubordinateId(UUID managerId, UUID subordinateId) {
        this();

        this.managerId = managerId.toString();
        this.subordinateId = subordinateId.toString();
    }

    public UUID getManagerId() {
        return UUID.fromString(managerId);
    }

    public void setManagerId(UUID managerId) {
        this.managerId = managerId.toString();
    }

    public UUID getSubordinateId() {
        return UUID.fromString(subordinateId);
    }

    public void setSubordinateId(UUID subordinateId) {
        this.subordinateId = subordinateId.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return managerId.hashCode() + subordinateId.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if(obj == null)
            return false;

        if(!(obj instanceof ManagerSubordinateId))
            return false;

        ManagerSubordinateId other = (ManagerSubordinateId) obj;
        if(!(other.getManagerId().equals(getManagerId())) ||
            !(other.getSubordinateId().equals(getSubordinateId()))) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}

@Entity
    @Table(name = "managers_subordinates", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(name = "UK_MANAGER_SUBORDINATE",
        columnNames = { "manager_guid", "subordinate_guid", "management_type" }))
    public class ManagerSubordinate implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 7676137409755328186L;

        @EmbeddedId
        @NotNull
        @Valid
        private ManagerSubordinateId managerSubordinateId;

        @MapsId("managerId")
        @JoinColumn(name = "manager_guid", nullable = false, insertable = false,
            updatable = false, foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_EMPLOYEE_MANAGER",
                value = ConstraintMode.CONSTRAINT))
        @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {
            CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH,
            CascadeType.DETACH })
        @NotNull
        @Valid
        private Employee manager;

        @MapsId("subordinateId")
        @JoinColumn(name = "subordinate_guid", nullable = false, insertable = false,
            updatable = false, foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_EMPLOYEE_SUBORDINATE",
                value = ConstraintMode.CONSTRAINT))
        @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {
            CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH,
            CascadeType.DETACH })
        @NotNull
        @Valid
        private Employee subordinate;

        @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
        @Column(name = "management_type", nullable = false)
        @NotNull
        private ManagementType managementType;

        protected ManagerSubordinate() {
        }

        public ManagerSubordinate(ManagerSubordinateId managerSubordinateId, Employee manager, Employee subordinate,
            ManagementType managementType) {
            this();

            this.managerSubordinateId = managerSubordinateId;
            this.manager = manager;
            this.subordinate = subordinate;
            this.managementType = managementType;
        }

        public ManagerSubordinateId getManagerSubordinateId() {
            return managerSubordinateId;
        }

        public void setManagerSubordinateId(ManagerSubordinateId managerSubordinateId) {
            this.managerSubordinateId = managerSubordinateId;
        }

        public Employee getManager() {
            return manager;
        }

        public void setManager(Employee manager) {
            this.manager = manager;
        }

        public Employee getSubordinate() {
            return subordinate;
        }

        public void setSubordinate(Employee subordinate) {
            this.subordinate = subordinate;
        }

        public ManagementType getManagementType() {
            return managementType;
        }

        public void setManagementType(ManagementType managementType) {
            this.managementType = managementType;
        }
    }
```

When I try to save employee like this:

```
Role employeeRole = new Role("Employee");

Employee employee = new Employee(UUID.randomUUID(), Arrays.asList(employeeRole));

employeeRole.getEmployees().add(employee);

employeeRepository.save(employee);
```

saving fails because of constraint validation error which says that roles field inside employee is empty even if it's not (roles are passed to the constructor). It looks like there is some issue with @NotEmpty annotation. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: not sure, may be you already tried this, if not try .. put a debug point on `employeeRepository.save(employee);` and see if the employee has the roles list. Also, create a `employee` object statically like Employee emp = new Employee(); and set its fields and try to save it directly just on the place where you are trying to save now

Comment: Already tried that and I'm getting the same result. I have made default constructor protected to ensure that user must provide some values to the constructor.

Comment: ok, i could not find out the issue reading it over and over, perhaps i should try it  myself with an embedded db

Comment: Ok. I will add implementation for ManagerSubordinateId class.

Comment: I feel the mapping between Employees and Roles is somewhere wrong. Will update

Answer (score 0):

I have come across a similar problem, there seems to be a bug in hibernate. The problem presents itself when validating a Set, or using CascadeType.MERGE, This issue only presents when not using one of the hibernate provided @Id generation strategies.
Seems like you have the same issue [HHH-10246](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-10246)

Comment: Fixed in version 5.2.0 of Hibernate